# When trying to find the maximum number in TypeScript, I am getting this error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently learning TypeScript and I am trying to solve this [Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a4ea304b3bfa89a9900008e/train/typescript) on Codewars.  I was able to solve it in JavaScript, but then when I tried solving it in TypeScript, I am getting an error which is explained below. I used the same approach from my JavaScript answer to answer the TypeScript version.

Here is the problem:  Given a number, I am to return the maximum number. So if I input 213, I am supposed to return 312 as you see below:

```
maxNumber (213) ==> return (321)
```

This is the solution I came up with for JavaScript.

```
    function maxNumber(number) {
  
    var num = String(number).split('').sort().reverse().join('');
    return num;
    }

   const answer = maxNumber(1234)
    console.log(answer)
    //Output: 4321
```

I tried the same, but in TypeScript, but I keep getting the error message: **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.**

```
export function maxNumber(n: number): number {
  var num = String(n).split('').sort().reverse().join('');
  return num;
}

const answer = maxNumber(1234)
console.log(answer)
```

So then my response to that error was taking the number that is being entered, convert it to a string, then using the split method to convert it back into a number inside of an array, but I am getting the same error message.

```
export function maxNumber(n: number): number {
  var num = n.toString();
  
  var numNew = num.split('').sort().reverse().join('');
   
  return numNew;
  
}

const answer = maxNumber(1234)
console.log(answer)
```

I know what it is saying, but I can't assign the type string to `n` and then return a number. Is there a way to fix this? I know that as a result of using TypeScript, it is supposed to find errors like this, which may not be found when just using JavaScript.

Comment: That function *does* return a string, what were you expecting?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't complain that `num` is a number that should be a string, but that `numNew` is a string that should be a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parseInt to return the value as a number:

```
return parseInt(numNew, 10); // the 10 specifies base 10 (decimal)
```

Note that even in the Javascript version, you are returning a string not a number, which will be a problem if code calling your functions expects a number and does a comparison on the result or otherwise treats it as an integer, so the solution above should be applied in both cases.